# 301 Redirect Dynamic URL with .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic

I have dynamic URL that I want to redirect (301) with .htaccess.

Old URL:
mysite.com/index.php?route=product/search&**keyword**=*searchphrase*

New URL:
mysite.com/index.php?route=product/search&**search**=*searchphrase*

I need that the redirect will change the URL from search&**keyword** to search&**search**, but will keep the *searchphrase*.

How to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(index\.php\?route=product/search)&keyword=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1&search=%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Hi,

mod_rewrite is enable.

I added the lines to my .htaccess, but it's still send me to the original page. Should I wait that the server will update this or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Working good, but the search phrase is on Hebrew language, and it's showing this: %D7%92%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9C
and it's should show this: גריל

Comment: Working like a CHARM!

Thanks Man!